# matlab scatter plot time series

Tags: matlab, data-analysis

I would like to look at two dimensional data in a time-series - the first idea I had was to use a scatter plot, where you can easily explore timepoint-to-timepoint. Is there a function I could use for this? I looked at scatter3 but it can only plot perfectly-cubic data, not as below:

e.g.

```
data=rand(5,5,3);
scatter3(data(1,:,:),data(:,1,:),data(:,:,1)) %throws an error
```

thanks

edit: Originally I had something like >[this](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scriptable/bubble.html)< in mind

Answer (score 1):

scatter3 seems to be for 3D plots, but you say your data is 2D.

For a simple time-series graph you could presumably even just use plot:

```
figure
nPoints = 25;
dataX = 1:nPoints;
dataY = rand(1,nPoints);
plot(dataX,dataY, 'o-')
```

However, the example you give in your link looks like something else, so it seems like scatter (rather than scatter3) might be what you're after. Maybe something like this?

```
figure
nPoints = 25;
dataX = 1:nPoints;
dataY = rand(1,nPoints);
dataArea = rand(1,nPoints)*100;
dataColours = rand(nPoints,3);

scatter(dataX,dataY,dataArea,dataColours)
```

EDIT:
I think I understand better what you mean, sorry I didn't see the buttons at the bottom of the link, but correct me if I'm wrong. So you have a set of XY coordinates for multiple objects at different points in time, and ideally you want to plot how the XY coordinates of each object (in 2 dimensions) change over time (in 3 dimensions). Your initial approach in using scatter3 was to try and make a simple 3d graph, but maybe ideally you want a 2d graph that can be either animated or interactive, to change the time point displayed at any given time?

Going back to your original question, I think the issue with your attempt to use scatter3 (or plot3 might be useful too) is I'm not sure what your dummy data would represent. You created data as a 5x5x3 matrix, and I assume that might represent 25 data points, at 3 different time intervals? However, which data would represent the X and which the Y coordinates? It would work with something like the following, where each variable represents the X/Y/Z coordinates of 6  objects (columns) at 5 different time points (rows)

```
myX = rand(5,6,1);
myY = rand(5,6,1);
% I'm making each time point increase linearly.
myZ = repmat((1:size(myX,1))', 1, size(myX,2));
plot3(myX, myY, myZ, 'o-')
grid on
% Note I find the default dimensions it treats as X, Y and Z unintuitive (e.g. the Z dimension is the vertical dimension), but one could swap the input arguments around to overcome this.
```

However, especially if you have a lot of points, I'm not sure how clear a graph like this will be, especially compared to the example in your link.

Instead it seems like you ideally want only the XY coordinates of all objects to be plotted for only one time point at once, and a way to cycle through each time point sequentially. This seems trickier, and maybe someone else will be able to answer better than I have. A couple more questions though that might be useful:

- How much do you care about the smoothness of the transition. In the example link the circles move smoothly from one position to another, rather than just jumping/teleporting between points.
- Ideally do you want a function that would produce an 'animation', cycling through all the time points from begining to end, or a way of manually specifying/changing which time point is being displayed. If the former, maybe this function would be useful (though I've tried it myself yet) https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42305-multicomet

Comment: imagine it as a movie, the question is basically how do I get a movie of this 2D data. Naturally, my mind jumped to 3D data. The last plot of yours is ok, but then I want a time series of that, as in, like on the website, press 'randomize' to get new data. I want to follow the change of those data points